# Selenium not working on boot Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, selenium, cron, raspberry-pi

So I have the small following script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

time.sleep(60)
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Create a new text file!')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://mediamere.com")
```

The issue is that it creates a file, but doesn't open the web page. The script is called using this line in my crontab file:

`@reboot python /home/pi/test.py`

Does anybody know why my web page is not opening?
What's also weird is that if I call it myself using `python /home/pi/test.py` (after the system is booted) it works fine

Comment: Have you tried running the script manually (i.e. not as part of a reboot)?

Comment: Also, are you _sure_ the file is being re-created when the script runs?  Have you checked the timestamp?  The filename and contents don't change, so the mere existence of the file doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you passed no webdriver to the function just the path. You need to pass the .exe-file. And maybe try the absolute path.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

time.sleep(60)
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Create a new text file!')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://mediamere.com")
```